# Chromedriver, Google Chrome, Linux, headless, using client (authentication) certificate

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, authentication, selenium-chromedriver, chromium

I am running automated tests under Linux (CentOS) in headless mode.

I got a site where I need to provide an SSL certificate for HTTP SSL client authentication. The file is .p12 format, I installed it the same way on two machines (VM running CentOS with UI, the other is a normal headless server, again running CentOS).

Using pk12util I installed the certificate in the browser store, confirmed successful installation, then added the policy for Chrome to use the certificate automatically for the website in question.

Now the fun starts. In the VM where I have UI, I run the browser in headful mode, everything works perfectly. However, when on either machine I run the browser in headless mode, I need it to run headless for the server, I get the following errors in the driver log:

```
[DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Response: Page.navigate (id=18) 5944A53229353F1849E7D2D15FA4A11C {

"errorText": "net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR",

"frameId": "5944A53229353F1849E7D2D15FA4A11C",

"loaderId": "4F3404B14470DD65090915C651B3D3EC"

}

...

[cf5020dd474256cce9c41538b1ffa0c2] RESPONSE Navigate ERROR unknown error: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

While running in headless mode, I switched on the debug port, 9222, and I see in the Network tab that the request failed with the error "Failed to load response data: No resource with given identifier found".

Before installing the SSL certificate I had the same error in headful mode, but when I installed the certificate and added the policy, it went away, which makes me think that for whatever reason, the headless Chrome can't find the certificate.

Did I miss something? Can we provide SSL client certificates in headless mode? Does anybody have any suggestions?

Thanks!

PS: In headless mode the browser is started with the usual flags: acceptInsecureCerts=true, --ignore-certificate-errors, --ignore-urlfetcher-cert-requests.

I am running under CentOS 7.9, Chrome v.99

Answer (score 0):

Well I actually found the answer.
Unfortunately, it does not work!!!

It is all explained in the following issue.
Issue 1310715: Headless Chrome not using installed client (authentication) certificates from the store.

**This issue shows the steps to reproduce.**

UserAgent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.82 Safari/537.36

Steps to reproduce the problem:

Have a website behind a webserver that has browser client authentication with an SSL certificate.
Install the certificate in the certificate store of Chrome under $HOME/pki/nssdb folder. My certificate was in pk12 format, so I used pk12util to install it.
The installation must exit with: 'pk12util: PKCS12 IMPORT SUCCESSFUL' message.
Add a policy to your website under /etc/opt/chrome/policies/managed, so that Chrome provides the certificate automatically to the site's webserver.
Open the website.
What is the expected behavior? When the browser is started in headless or headful mode, the browser should provide the certificate to the webserver and proceed further.

What went wrong? Only in headful mode does the browser provide the certificate to the webserver. Headless mode does not. There's this error in the logs:

**The issue response states the following:**

Headless Chrome doesn't currently implement client certs. Switching this to a feature request that the headless folks can triage. Mechanically, client certs are come out of //content via CreateClientCertStore and SelectClientCertificate. Headless doesn't have a way to show UI, so it always continues without a client certificate.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1310715&q=component%3AInternals%3EHeadless&can=2